# ASP.NET GridView focus selected row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am fairly new to ASP.NET. I have a `GridView` control which has many rows. Based on selection of each row I need to enable/disable few list and text controls on the collapsible panel in a ASCX.

The issue I am facing is whenever I select any row the `GridView` sets the focus on the first row all the time due to postback.

How do I set the focus on the selected row?

Can I use `GetPostBackClientHyperlink` in the `RowDataBound` somehow to register a client-side script?

Reply with some code is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Add a handler to the SelectedIndexChanged event of your GridView and insert the following code into this handler:

```
GridView1.SelectedRow.Focus(); // where GridView1 is the name of your GridView
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jQuery. I added a `<div>` with an ID that is only shown when a row is using the edit template.
`$('#hiddenDIV').focus();`